# Unexpected behaviour found while dealing with a pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Look at the code given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int (*p)[3];
     int a[3]={10,11,12};
     p=&a;
     printf("%d\n", *p[0]);
     printf("%d\n", *p[1]);
     printf("%d\n", *p[2]);
     return 0;
}
```

printf("%d\n", *p[0]); prints 10 which is expected.

But printf("%d\n", *p[1]); doesn't print 11.

And 
printf("%d\n", *p[2]); doesn't print 12.

Why? What's the reason behind this?

Comment: `*p[k]` is `*(p[k])`, not `(*p)[k]`.

Comment: are you aware that `p` is an array of three pointers of which one points to `a[0]` and the others to unkown memory?

Comment: Use a simple pointer (int *p;) and increment the pointer to show the other values of your array.

Comment: No. I thought p is an array of three pointers of which one points to a[0], one to a[1] and one to a[2]. I may have mistaken. But why the other pointers except p[0] point to unknown memory? @Kami Kaze

Answer (score 4):

Operator precedence. `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so when you write `*p[0]` it is the same as `(*(*(p + 0)))` - you do pointer arithmetic on an array pointer.

Meaning that for example `p[1]` gives you the address of `p` + `3*sizeof(int)` bytes, which is accessing the array out of bounds.

Correct code should be:

```
 printf("%d\n", (*p)[0]);
 printf("%d\n", (*p)[1]);
 printf("%d\n", (*p)[2]);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that C declarations were designed so that they mirror their usage. So if you needed to declare p as `int (*p)[3]` that's probably how you need to use it too. i.e. `foo = (*p)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

`*p[k]` is `*(p[k])`, not `(*p)[k]`.

That you get the expected result for `*p[0]` can be explained by its being the same as `p[0][0]`, and it doesn't matter which order you put the zeros in.

`p[1][0]` (`*p[1]`), however, is not the same as `p[0][1]` (`(*p)[1]`).
(It's even undefined, since `p[1]` does not exist.)

Answer (score 0):

`int (*p)[3];` is an array of pointers to `int`.

`int a[3]={10,11,12};` is an array of `int`. Arrays and pointers share a lot of properties. You can use array notation for pointers for example.

Lets take a normal pointer `int *p = a` which is the same as `int *p = &a[0]`. Now the pointer points to the first element of the array. And you can use it the same way as the array.

```
 printf("%d\n", p[0]); //10
 printf("%d\n", p[1]); //11
 printf("%d\n", p[2]); //12
```

What you did was getting the address of the array-"pointer" this yields the address of the first element of the array. Because `&a == a`

This gets written to the first element of your pointer array leaving you with

```
p[0] == a
p[1] == unknown
p[2] == unknown
```

by doing `*p[0]` you get the first element of p (`p[0]`) and dereference it `*`.
This is the same as `*a` or `a[0]`.

But by doing `*p[1]` you get to an unkown memory location(`p[1]`) and derefence it `*`. This is undefined behaviour.